Update issue on .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid Application to .NET 9 from .NET 8
I maintaining .NET 8 MAUI Blazor Hybrid project. that was created when .NET 7 available. then I update it to .NET 8 and it works fine. But when I updating it to .NET 9 also seems good but when I publishing Android Signed app bundle from Command Line I got issue like zip files are not found. are there any workaround?
here is my CLI Log
[232/234] Java.Interop.dll -> Java.Interop.dll.so
  [233/234] Mono.Android.dll -> Mono.Android.dll.so
  [234/234] System.Private.CoreLib.dll -> System.Private.CoreLib.dll.so
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\0wz98yz2xy-ln71fuhiq0.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\0wz98yz2xy-ln71fuhiq0.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\3t6q0cs9y8-43m9p5349d.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\3t6q0cs9y8-43m9p5349d.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\4l3s7nsc0j-8x4eooawvc.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\4l3s7nsc0j-8x4eooawvc.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\jposvdsglt-h5gslb8p3n.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\jposvdsglt-h5gslb8p3n.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\n12flnyxzq-qvny4wtqki.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\n12flnyxzq-qvny4wtqki.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\q731hh5ls5-fipu15mg5j.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\q731hh5ls5-fipu15mg5j.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\tzxjg6is5z-mj9omvu2v8.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\tzxjg6is5z-mj9omvu2v8.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\w4ra1jcf9h-luzdqbu196.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\w4ra1jcf9h-luzdqbu196.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\yuj0dz1wdz-lvbl4zggu8.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\yuj0dz1wdz-lvbl4zggu8.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\x1cogavxrv-erjoepzw21.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\x1cogavxrv-erjoepzw21.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]
<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\x1cogavxrv-erjoepzw21.gz : error XA2001: Source file '<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti\obj\Release\net9.0\compressed\x1cogavxrv-erjoepzw21.gz' could not be found. [<path>\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid\bluelotus360.com.mauimulti.Droid.csproj]

##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.

I tried cleaning and rebuilding in visual studio and updating some vulnerable dependencies as well. but seems not work fine.

Any particular reason you want to upgrade from .NET 8.0? It's LTS, whereas .NET 9.0 isn't.  The end-of-support date for .NET 8.0 is November 2026, whereas the end-of-support date for .NET 9.0 is May 2026.

for experiment about hybrid cache they introduced.
